# Generate diagrams for Haskell code

Tags: haskell, documentation, visualization

Is there something that is kind of a cross between graphmod and haddock? I want a diagram like graphmod showing dependencies/relationships, but I want to include additional documentation in the diagram.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not an existing one.  Here are the list of available Haskell visualisation utilities (at least those on Hackage):

- [graphmod](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphmod) which you've already found: visualise module dependencies.
- [prof2dot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prof2dot) visualise profiling reports
- [hs2dot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hs2dot) visualise Haskell code
- [vacuum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum) (and related packages) visualises the data structures at run-time
- [SourceGraph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph) (disclaimer: this is mine) aims to provide different forms of visualisation of the call graphs and perform some analyses; haven't had much time to work on this lately though.
- [graphtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphtype) is for comparing data types

It may be possible to use doxygen to generate documentation with visualisation, but a quick Google didn't reveal any work on providing support for Haskell in doxygen (and it would require different markup than what Haddock uses).